# sequence and limit convergence proof help

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I need help with a proof that I'm stuck on.

> Question: Suppose $a_n$ converges to $a > 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and that $a_n > 0$ for all natural numbers $n$. Show that $m > 0$ exists so that $a_n \geq m$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

My incomplete proof: Let $\epsilon = |a|/2$. Then, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n - a| < |a|/2 = \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. By the triangle inequality, $||a_n| - |a|| \leq |a_n - a| < |a|/2$. In particular, $|a_n| - |a| < |a|/2$. Then, since $a$, $a_n$ are positive, $a_n - a < a/2$.

This is where I'm stuck. We did the opposite problem before and took the max here. I believe I need to take the min of $a_1 , a_2 ,\ldots , a_N , 3a/2$, but I don't know what the min would be or how that would necessarily help me, since I don't have an in the set. I also saw something in the notes that said:

By the triangle inequality, $|a_n| = |a_n - a + a| \geq |a| - |a_n - a| > |a|/2$.

Which may help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take $m=\min\{a_1,\cdots,a_N, \frac{a}{2}\}$, then you have that

1) $a_n\ge m$ for $1\le n\le N\;\;$ and  $\;\;$2) $a_n>\frac{a}{2}\ge m$ for $n\ge N$ as well

$\hspace{2.3 in}$(since $n\ge N\implies|a_n-a|<\frac{a}{2}\implies a_n>\frac{a}{2}$)

Comment: Why is the implication you wrote true? Also, for 1, why do you have 1 <= n <= N?

Comment: @user269711 Sorry for the delay in answering. Since $|a_n-a|<\frac{a}{2}$, $-\frac{a}{2}<a_n-a<\frac{a}{2}$; so$ \frac{a}{2}<a_n<\frac{3a}{2}$.  In 1), we know that $a_1\ge m, \cdots, a_N\ge m$ by the definition of $m$; and that is all that 1) is saying.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a_n\to a$, we may choose $N$ such that $n\geqslant N$ implies $|a_n-a|<\frac a2$. In particular, $a_n >\frac a2$ for $n\geqslant N$. Set $m=\max\left\{a_1,\ldots, a_{N-1}, \frac a2\right\}$. Then $a_n\geqslant m>0$ for all $n$.

For clarity, I will explicitly define $\max$. For two real numbers $x,y$, define

$$
\max\{x,y\} = 
\begin{cases} x,& x>y\\
y,& y\geqslant x.
\end{cases}
$$

Given real numbers $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, recursively define

$$\max\{x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}\} = \max\{\max\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}, x_{n+1}\}. $$

Comment: I'm missing something here. I can use the triangle inequality to get it down to  an - a < a/2. How are you getting it down to an > a/2?

Comment: If $|a_n-a|<\frac a2$, then $a-a_n<\frac a2$. Hence $\frac a2< a_n$.

Comment: Also, what would the max m be?

Comment: I explicitly defined $m$ in my answer...

Comment: So, since |an - a | < a/2, then - |an - a| < a/2. Then, -an+a < a/2, and it follows that an > a/2?

Comment: I meant does it matter what in that set is the max element?

Comment: Yes. Recall that $|x| < y$ if and only if $x < y$ and $-x < y$.

Comment: I understand where you got that from now. Thank you!